# Python private inheritance? How to trick isinstance()?

Tags: python, database, django, orm

Snippet of django core code:

```
class ForeignKey(RelatedField, Field):

    ...

    def db_type(self, connection):
        rel_field = self.rel.get_related_field()
        if (isinstance(rel_field, AutoField) or
                (not connection.features.related_fields_match_type and
                isinstance(rel_field, (PositiveIntegerField,
                                       PositiveSmallIntegerField)))):
            return IntegerField().db_type(connection=connection)
        return rel_field.db_type(connection=connection)
```

This code is very bad, because if I define a custom field which inherits from `AutoField`, then my db_type method will be ignored.

What I would like to do is to hide the fact that my class is an instance of `AutoField`. In C++, I would do that by private inheritance.

Is there any way to trick `isinstance` to return `False` or to hide inheritance?

Code of my cutom field:

```
class MyAutoField(models.AutoField):

    def __init__(self, length, *args, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        super(MyAutoField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'oracle':
            return 'NUMBER(%s,0)' % (self.length)
        if connection.vendor == 'postgresql':
            if self.length <= 4:
                return 'smallint'
            if self.length <= 9:
                return 'integer'
            return 'bigint'
        return super(MyAutoField, self).db_type(connection)
```

Comment: When you say "which is an instance of", do you mean "inherits"?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - exactly that! Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

So I have a way to do it, but its via "monkey patching."  You can't use `ABCMeta` because that requires you override your base class's metaclass.

You could "change" isinstance as follows.  It is important that "patches" only gets imported once, and I would only do this if is no other way.

**patches.py**

```
import django.models
import mymodel
import __builtin__
def _isinstance(instance, clz):
    if clz is models.AutoField and isinstance_orig(instance, MyAutoField):
        return False
    return isinstance_orig(instance, clz)
__builtin__.isinstance_orig = __builtin__.isinstance
__builtin__.isinstance = _isinstance
```

Then your test program:

```
class MyAutoField(models.AutoField): pass

x = MyAutoField()
print(isinstance(x, models.AutoField))
print(isinstance(x, models.MyAutoField))
```

---

Introducing Abstract Base Classes:  [PEP-3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) .  Below is an abstract example...

```
class ABCMeta(type):

  def __instancecheck__(cls, inst):
    """Implement isinstance(inst, cls)."""
    return any(cls.__subclasscheck__(c)
               for c in {type(inst), inst.__class__})

  def __subclasscheck__(cls, sub):
    """Implement issubclass(sub, cls)."""
    candidates = cls.__dict__.get("__subclass__", set()) | {cls}
    return any(c in candidates for c in sub.mro())
```

Comment: I don't know how to apply this answer to my case :(

Comment: Well you need to explain your:  `because if I define a custom field which inherits from AutoField.`

Comment: No better explanation than actuall code - Question is corrected now.